# How to copy all data from one collection to another

Tags: javascript, mongodb, join, copy, aggregate

Exaplaining the scenario:

1. I have a backup collection `auditdata_history` which has 2.6 million unique records currently
2. It was created from another collection `auditdata` whose data is backed up every day to `auditdata_history`. Currently `auditdata` has 800k records

There is an issue now and i want to transfer back all the data from `auditdata_history` to `auditdata` so customer can use it.

One way to achieve this is using `forEach` loop and inserting data one by one back.
I want another quicker approach of copying all data from `auditdata_history` to `auditdata`. I researched and found aggregate:

```
db.collection1_backup.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "collection1" } ])
```

But the above will delete all data from collection1 which i dont want.
Can someone help me with this simple requirement of copying all data from `auditdata_history` back to `auditdata`

Comment: Have you checked out [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)?

Comment: Check out [renameCollection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/#db.collection.renamecollection--)

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `insertMany()` method to insert all documents from the `auditdata_history` collection into the `auditdata` collection without removing the existing data.

for example:

```
// Get all documents from auditdata_history
var docs = db.auditdata_history.find();

// Insert all documents into auditdata
db.auditdata.insertMany(docs);
```

This will insert all the documents from `auditdata_history` into `auditdata` without removing any existing data. Note that this will not preserve the `_id` values of the documents, so if you need to keep the original `_id` values, you will need to handle that separately.

It's important to keep in mind that this can be a potentially slow operation, especially if the collections are very large, so it's recommended to perform this operation during a maintenance window or when the application can tolerate some downtime.